# I cannot initialize date picker with init() or update() method in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a `DatePicker` and I am trying to initialize it as follows:

```
    DatePicker dp_up = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    String inputPattern = "MMM dd, yyyy";
    String outputPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
    Date date = null;
    String str = null;
    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(GDate);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
        String Astr[] = str.split("/");
        int myday = Integer.parseInt(Astr[0]);
        int mymonth = Integer.parseInt(Astr[1]);
        int myyear = Integer.parseInt(Astr[2]);

        **dp_up.updateDate(myyear, mymonth-1, myday);**

        OR

        **dp_up.init(myyear, mymonth-1, myday,null);**

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My variables contain their int values but it keeps showing current date and not the one I want.

The XML of Date Picker is

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:padding="2dp" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for exception if you caught

Comment: how I can check for exception?

Comment: Check log. I think you are getting parse exception..

Comment: What's the content of `GDate`?

Comment: The value of GDate is Oct 21, 2016

Comment: @PankajKumar nothing in log about parsing exception

Comment: I see no issue when using `dp_up.updateDate(myyear, mymonth-1, myday)`

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code accordingly, and it works fine. I put it in onCreate after the setContentView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatePicker dp_up = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    String inputPattern = "MMM dd, yyyy";
    String outputPattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
    Date date = null;
    String str = null;
    try {
        String GDate = "Oct 21, 2016";
        date = inputFormat.parse(GDate);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
        String Astr[] = str.split("/");
        int myday = Integer.parseInt(Astr[0]);
        int mymonth = Integer.parseInt(Astr[1]);
        int myyear = Integer.parseInt(Astr[2]);

        dp_up.updateDate(myyear, mymonth-1, myday);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My layout as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.elyeproj.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></DatePicker>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could try this code and see if it works? I tried on Android M on Nexus 5 emulator device.

Comment: It still not working with String GDate = "Oct 21, 2016"; I simplified DatePicker XML like yours but nothing

Comment: Perhaps you could also change your layout, to ensure you point to the actual dataPicker... Are you using the latest version of Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I had defined my datePicker Listener like

```
dp.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {}
```

few lines after my code and it got all the time the current date So I put a variable flag to distinguish between new entry or update